# resolve subdomains on a LAN test server

Tags: apache, testing, ubuntu, dns, lan

I have a development machine "A" and a test server "B". A runs Windows, "B" runs ubuntu. I've set up correctly machine "B" (apache, /etc/hosts) so that e.g. curl site.B and curl site.localhost both give correct result. From windows (machine "A") when I curl site.B I get "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'site.B'". Do you have any clues on how to resolve this issue? (HINT: it might be Windows or router hostname caching issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows also has a `hosts` file that you need to configure.  The problem is that Microsoft spells `/etc` as `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc`.  :-)

See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) for details.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I just checked this and it works but OMG - is it the only way? This means that if I had 5 developers in the LAN I should run from one machine to the other to edit their hosts files and adding also two entries per subdomain e.g. site.B and www.site.B. I would expect there to be a muuuuch faster/scalable way

Comment: The scalable way is to run your own authoritative DNS for your domain, which is what most corporations do inside their firewalls.  Alternatively, use hostnames without periods in them, which confuse the network stacks into thinking they're different domains.

Comment: That's great to know. Just for reference, could you post me a link for setting up ubuntu DNS that you would recommend? Thanks a million!

Comment: ... or you could Google _ubuntu dns_ and save us both the trouble.

Comment: :) I prefer "ubuntu dns tutorial" and this one looks quite comprehensive: http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/ Thanks once again!